# Create properties of class and project to them at the runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, datatable

I am getting columns from the `DataTable` at the runtime from the stored procedure. Code looks like this:

```
var parkDataTable = new DataTable("tmp");
...
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FooStoredProcedure", db.Database.Connection as 
    SqlConnection, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
parkDataTable.Load(dr);
```

The interesting thing that my columns can have various names by adding date to a column name. For example, I have a column name `2017-09-01_FactPark`, then the next time it can be `2017-10-01_FactPark`. Please, see the following image with the columns:

[image]

**I can know about column names and quantity of columns just at the runtime.**

Is it possible to create a class with the above columns as properties at the runtime and project them to these properties like usual way:

```
public IQueryable<EmployeeDTO> GetEmployees()
{
    return db.Employees
        .Select(employee => new EmployeeDTO
        {
            ID = employee.ID,                    
            FirstName = employee.PriceNumber,
            LastName = employee.PriceDate                                        
        }).AsQueryable();
}
```

So my goal is to create class with properties from the `DataTable` and project `DataTable` columns to the class with properties.

Is it possible to create properties at the runtime and project `DataTable` columns to newly created properties of class?

Comment: *2017-0901_FactPark*, *2017-10-01_FactPark*... Someone needs normalization...

Comment: You can't or isn't allowed? :)

Comment: @JohnyL column names are created by `SELECT` statement of stored procedure and I am not allowed to change this `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track in trying to force dynamic columns into statically defined properties. Why not expose the dynamic fields as a key/value collection? That would allow you to enumerate and lookup the values without recompiling the code. I.e. the stored proc could change but your code wouldn't need to.

Comment: How are you planing to consume the query result? sure you can't use the class in code since the properties is generated at runtime

Comment: @MarnixvanValen I try to do in this way as I need to have a DTO class to create fields.

Comment: @StepUp the only possible way I can see is to loop trough `DataTable` columns first (when generated), then use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to create properties.

Comment: @Yollo ok, do you know the way how to project to these properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to dynamically constitute the shape of your class is with `DynamicObject` class. You can create your own dynamic class which would set and fetch properties with their values.

For now, let's implement our dynamic class:

```
using System.Dynamic;

class Dynamo : DynamicObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> items = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return items.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        items[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, object value)
    {
        string propName = indexes[0] as string;
        items[propName] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {
        string propName = indexes[0] as string;
        return items.TryGetValue(propName, out result);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return items.Keys;
    }
}
```

What we have here:

1. `items` dictionary. Allows us to store any value and fetch it by its name.
2. `TryGetMember()/TrySetMember()` methods. This group allows us to set/fetch values with `Dot-Property` notation: `Class.Property`.
3. `TrySetIndex()/TryGetIndex()` methods. This group allows us to set/fetch values with `Indexer` notation: `Class[varHoldingPropName]` or `Class["propName"]`.
4. `GetDynamicMemberNames()` method. Allows to retrieve all properties names.

In order to set property names, you must use `Indexer` notation, because with `Dot-Property` notation the binder will use your property name as identifier name, while `Indexer` will evaluate your variable:

```
static void UseDynamicObject()
{

    var colorProperty = "Color";
    var ageProperty = "Age";

    dynamic dynamo = new Dynamo();
    dynamo.colorProperty = "red";
    dynamo[ageProperty] = 20;

    // DOT-PROPERTY NOTATION
    // Error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
    // 'Dynamo' does not contain a definition for 'Color'.
    Console.WriteLine(dynamo.Color);
    // The property used to retrieve value "red" is "colorProperty" rather "Color".
    Console.WriteLine(dynamo.colorProperty);

    // INDEXER NOTATION
    // We can use either variable or literal name of the property,
    // so these two lines are equivalent.
    Console.WriteLine(dynamo[ageProperty]);
    Console.WriteLine(dynamo["Age"]);

}
```

The logic for app is following: you could fetch columns' names from `SqlDataReader` and use them for setting them on your dynamic object.

Here's one possible variant of using SqlDataReader and our dynamic class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var data = new List<dynamic>();
    List<string> cols = default;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Client", conn))
        {
            using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Get columns names
                cols = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                       .Select(i => reader.GetName(i)).ToList();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dynamic obj = new Dynamo();
                    cols.ForEach(c => obj[c] = reader[c]);
                    data.Add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /* OUTPUT DATA */

    // To get columns names, you can:
    // 1) use ready "cols" variable
    // 2) use "GetDynamicMemberNames()" on first object:
    //    IEnumerable<string> cols = data[0].GetDynamicMemberNames();
    foreach (var obj in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", cols.Select(c => $"{c} = {obj[c]}")));
    }

    // Output:
    // ClientId = 1, ClientName = Client1
    // ClientId = 2, ClientName = Client2

}
```

Comment: No chance to test, but I believe to you:)

Comment: @JohnyL nice, i was wondering the same question two months ago, but didn't post it could this be done using `ExpandoObjects`?

Comment: @Yollo Expando doesn't allow you use Indexer, i.e. you can't write this way: exp["Age"] = 100. The error says: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ExpandoObject`.