# Is there a way to change property name afterwards? (c#)

Tags: c#, properties, anonymous-types

For example, I am trying to create five anonymous objects to put in the `List`, but I want to name properties differently, is that possible?'

```
List<dynamic> myObjects = new List<dynamic>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     //do this
    var obj = new { Prop+i = "some value" };

       //or
    obj."somehow change property name here";

    myObjects.Add(obj);
}
```

So my properties would be named: Prop0, Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Prop4

Comment: I think, you want to do something strange. What is your real task? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Backs for example something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966620/create-properties-of-class-and-project-to-them-at-the-runtime)

Comment: I think, there are some better ways: use dictionary, or classes with inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Backs mentioned `ExpandoObject` can answer your problem, by casting `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionary<string, object>` you can treat the dictionary key as the property name:

```
List<dynamic> myObjects = new List<dynamic>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    //Add prop i property
    (obj as IDictionary<string, object>).Add("Prop"+i, "some value");
    //Remove prop i property
    (obj as IDictionary<string, object>).Remove("Prop"+i);
    //Add instead new property
    (obj as IDictionary<string, object>).Add("NewProp"+i, "some value");
    myObjects.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: this is a good explanation, Backs was right but I could not understand what he was trying to say, is there performance issue when doing something like this?

Comment: @Yollo many many many perfomance issues. `dynamic` is not the type use for perfomance

Comment: @Backs thank you , could you tell me is there a way of accessing tease properties by name afterwords? for example   `Console.WriteLine(obj["Prop"+i]);` i can't do it. (Cannot apply indexing  to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'')

Comment: @Yollo cast it first to IDictionary<string, object> : `Console.WriteLine(((IDictionary<string, object>)obj)["Prop"+i]);`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<dynamic> myObjects = new List<dynamic>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    obj.MyProperty = "some value";

    obj.ChangePropertyName = "change property name";

    myObjects.Add(obj);
}
```

But I don't know if it helps you :)

Comment: thank you for suggestion, first time I've heard about `ExpandoObjects`, but can I do something like this aftewards? `obj.ChangePropertyName = "myChangedName";  Console.WriteLine(obj.myChangedName);`

Comment: @Yollo just try

Comment: All I get in your answer is creating one more property.

Comment: @Yollo if you want to remove propety, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491577/in-c-how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-an-expandoobject

Comment: thank you, please checkout my edited [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47969696/7517846)